# Error creating item in dspace-cris-2022.02.00

Tags: dspace

I have the following problem sending items in Dspace Cris 2022.02.00 I will appreciate your help if possible please.

Characteristics
Dspace Chris 2022.02.00 | Ubuntu server 20.04 | postgresql 12 | tomcat 9

After creating a collection, be it Person, OrgUnit, Journal or any other value, the items are sent. In the graphic part, the message you get is: "There was a problem sending the article. Please try again later."

Checking the logs in /dspace/log/ I get the following:

2023-01-17 23:34:11,300 ERROR ef58dbeb-3f67-4cd3-b760-6197a8fbf95a 4698d980-dfcd-4b15-b2f7-dc0fcf4e2cbf org.dspace.app.rest.converter.AInprogressItemConverter @ An error occurred during the unmarshal of the data for the section correction - reported error: Relationship type isCorrectionOfItem does not exist
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Relationship type isCorrectionOfItem does not exist
at org.dspace.versioning.ItemCorrectionService.lambda$findRelationshipType$1(ItemCorrectionService.java:177) ~[dspace-api-cris-2022.02.00.jar:cris-2022.02.00]
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408) ~[?:?]

8dbeb-3f67-4cd3-b760-6197a8fbf95a 26c0ec2e-611c-4def-858f-971d5ee8e1c3 org.dspace.app.rest.exception.DSpaceApiExceptionControllerAdvice @ Request is invalid or incorrect (status:400 exception: Relationship type isCorrectionOfItem does not exist at: org.dspace.versioning.ItemCorrectionService.lambda$findRelationshipType$1(ItemCorrectionService.java:177))

2023-01-17 23:46:20,446 INFO  ef58dbeb-3f67-4cd3-b760-6197a8fbf95a 45c807f1-2458-4a67-8757-0c1735250a7e org.dspace.usage.LoggerUsageEventListener @ luis@bibliolatino.com::workflow_item:item_id=470ba0a5-4971-4bb0-b33f-4d5371d6bdaa
2023-01-17 23:46:20,456 WARN  ef58dbeb-3f67-4cd3-b760-6197a8fbf95a 45c807f1-2458-4a67-8757-0c1735250a7e org.dspace.app.rest.exception.DSpaceApiExceptionControllerAdvice @ Request is invalid or incorrect (status:400 exception: Relationship type isCorrectionOfItem does not exist at: org.dspace.versioning.ItemCorrectionService.lambda$findRelationshipType$1(ItemCorrectionService.java:177))

2023-01-17 23:46:20,456 WARN  ef58dbeb-3f67-4cd3-b760-6197a8fbf95a 45c807f1-2458-4a67-8757-0c1735250a7e org.dspace.app.rest.exception.DSpaceApiExceptionControllerAdvice @ Request is invalid or incorrect (status:400 exception: Relationship type isCorrectionOfItem does not exist at: org.dspace.versioning.ItemCorrectionService.lambda$findRelationshipType$1(ItemCorrectionService.java:177))

According to the documentation the following scripts were run

sudo /dspace/bin/dspace dsrun org.dspace.app.util.InitializeEntityTypesOnly -d
sudo /dspace/bin/dspace dsrun org.dspace.app.util.InitializeEntities -f correction-relationship-types.xml

No results for sending items in dspace cris

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined some new entities on the cris.cfg file? If this is the case you also have to add the related correction relationships on the correction-relationship-types.xml and then reimport it.

By the way, I can see you're running the dspace script using sudo which is not appropriate. This might cause some ownership change on some dspace file which might be also the cause of this or future issues. As a general rule, run the script with the same user you're running tomcat